# Can anyone tell me what this is?

Tags: equipment, pan

It looks to be a double boiler of some sort, but we're not sure what it is.

[image: strange pan]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an egg poacher.  Looks like [this exact model](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002CGSYBM).

[image: Egg Poacher]

Note that these don't really actually "poach" eggs, the result is more like a coddled egg. They do essentially work like double boilers.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a dab of butter in the bottom of the cup and and a raw egg over it, then steam it, you'll have coddled or shired eggs.